# vlc/mpv command line pipe live stream to standard output

Tags: ffmpeg, pipe, video-streaming, vlc, youtube-dl

I'm trying to capture a youtube/twitch/whatever stream and pipe it to vlc then pipe to other process (in bash wsl batch only due to weird behaviour with powershell pipe operator). I found out that `vlc` have the option `--sout` which is probably what I needed.

Since `vlc` don't support fetching from some site I tried to use `streamlink` or `youtube-dl` to download then I piped their output to `vlc` then pipe to `mpv`, `ffmpeg` or `ffplay` (I need vlc to accept standard input and pipe to standard output) as final pipe destination. Here is what I done so far:

```sh
# For now I'll use ffplay as final pipe destination and youtube-dl as downloader for demonstration purpose

# Test attempt

# These commands works as expected (bash wsl and batch):
youtube-dl.exe https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PrdYyWzO390 --output - | ffplay.exe -
streamlink https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PrdYyWzO390 best --output - | ffplay.exe -
youtube-dl.exe https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PrdYyWzO390 --output - | vlc.exe -

# (1) If the source is youtube and I try to download directly using vlc, vlc will open secondary console, and the command will not work (bash wsl and batch):
vlc.exe https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PrdYyWzO390 -I rc -vvv --sout="#std{mux=mp4,access=file,dst=-}" | ffplay.exe -

# I also have no idea if I need -vvv for output, and have to use -I rc (as using -I dummy do nothing), or omit -I rc entirely. I also have no idea if input_stream is equivalent to -

# First Attempt (bash wsl and batch)
# Probably naive approach

youtube-dl.exe https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PrdYyWzO390 --output - | vlc.exe - -I rc -vvv input_stream --sout="#std{mux=mp4,access=file,dst=-}" | ffplay.exe -

# => ffplay display nothing, vlc created secondary console also do nothing?

# Second Attempt (bash wsl)
# In this attempt I tried to copy everything from vcodec to vb (since I don't need transcoding) as I saw on videolan forums people keep putting transcoding option and I'm not sure if it necessary

youtube-dl.exe https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PrdYyWzO390 --output - | vlc.exe input_stream -I rc -vvv --sout="#transcode{vcodec=$vcodec,acodec=$acodec,ab=$arate,vb=$bitrate}:std{mux=mp4,access=file,dst=-}" | ffplay.exe -

# => same as above

# Third attempt (bash wsl)
# Tried to replace - with input_stream

youtube-dl.exe https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PrdYyWzO390 --output - | vlc.exe input_stream -I rc -vvv --sout="#std{mux=mp4,access=file,dst=-}" | ffplay.exe -

# => same thing as (1)
```

At this point I have no idea how to do this properly. I have tried to use python and using `subprocess` module to control `streamlink` and `vlc`, but that does not work either: https://pastebin.com/dHsPXA4i.

Any solution that are in bash wsl, powershell, batch or python will be appreciated.

P.S: I probably cannot use python LibVLC (it hard to explain but there's a proprietary plugin I'm needed to use and it only support vlc and mpv, and therefore have to control vlc program directly; I can also accept a solution that replace vlc with mpv but vlc-based problem are easier to "search" I guess)

(1): https://i.stack.imgur.com/if6ol.png

Comment: I see you ran `youtube-dl.exe https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=geJw6ikodMY --output -`. Keep in mind that youtube-dl and yt-dlp's stream video file option will only get a low or medium quality version of the video. Seems that you will have to download the video to a file to get the best audio+video (also make sure you have FFmpeg installed so it can combine YT's audio and video streams into one file).